# What is the maximum length of data passed to cassandra column

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is  there any limit on maximum length we can specify for a column while creating Cassandra table, if yes, then how much we can specify?

I am new to using Cassandra, please let me know

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The maximum number of cells (rows x columns) in a single partition is 2 billion and the maximum column key (and row key) size is 64KB and the maximum column value size is 2 GB. 
you can refer this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CASSANDRA2/CassandraLimitations

Comment: To build on what @Yasmeen said, the partition limitation is the smaller of 2 billion cells or the amount of data that can fit on a single node. For example, if you have only 1GB of space on node and each cell is 100MB, then the max size of the partition would be 10 cells. The reason is that a partition must fit on a single node (i.e. a partition cannot span nodes).

Comment: I believe we understand the billion as US billion 10^9

Comment: did not answer the length, but the size. there are different things.

Comment: Link is dead and there's no equivalent page in http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/

Comment: Possible new location: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CASSANDRA2/CassandraLimitations